# Null Pointer Exception while creating the mock object

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am new to the Junit. Please suggest what is going wrong in the below code -:

```
Mockito.when(daoimpl.getEcgs(request)).thenReturn(listOfecg);
```

getEcgs() takes the `DashboardRequest` object and the POJO if this class is as -:

```
public String eligibilityCarrierGroupId;
public Set<String> carrierIds;
@LastModifiedDate
public Date fromDate;
@LastModifiedDate
public Date toDate;
```

and the listOfecg POJO is

```
private String ecgId;
private List<String> carrier;
```

Now, consider i am setting up each and every field with some values and even after that i am getting the null pointer exceptions on

```
Mockito.when(daoimpl.getEcgs(request)).thenReturn(listOfecg);
```

Please advice me what might be going wrong.

Full Code-:

```
public class DashboardDataServiceTest {

    //Set<String> testSet = new HashSet<String>();

    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    @Mock
    private DashboardService dashboardService;
    @InjectMocks
    private DashboardDataController dashboardController;
    @InjectMocks
    DashboardDaoImpl daoimpl= new DashboardDaoImpl();

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(dashboardController).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testDashboardInfo() throws Exception {
        DashboardRequest request = new DashboardRequest();

        DashboardDataResponse response = new DashboardDataResponse();
        List<String> carrierIds = new ArrayList<>();
        Set<String> testSet = new HashSet<String>();
        carrierIds.add("KCY");
        List<DashboardStatusCount> overall = new ArrayList<>();
        DashboardStatusCount dashstatus = new DashboardStatusCount();
        dashstatus.setStatus("Success");
        dashstatus.setCount(12);
        overall.add(dashstatus);

        request.setEligibilityCarrierGroupId("aaa");
        testSet.add("KCY");
        request.setCarrierIds(testSet);
        request.setFromDate(new Date());
        request.setToDate(new Date());
        response.setOverallTotals(271);
        response.setOverall(overall);
        List<EligibilityCarrierGroupingDoc> listOfecg = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> carrierIdsx = new ArrayList<>();
        EligibilityCarrierGroupingDoc ecgDoc = new EligibilityCarrierGroupingDoc();
        ecgDoc.setEcgId("aaa");
        carrierIdsx.add("KCY");

        ecgDoc.setCarrier(carrierIdsx);
        listOfecg.add(ecgDoc);

        Mockito.when(daoimpl.getEcgs(request)).thenReturn(listOfecg);

        DashboardDataResponse responsedata = dashboardService.getDashBoardResponseData(request);
        System.out.println("The response data is "+responsedata);
    }
    private String mapToJson(Object object) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(object);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you creating your daoimpl mock? (impl is an odd name to include in a mock object).

Comment: Post your full code(test code part). Maybe your dao is null

Comment: Did you de bugged and checked weather internally it is your getEcgs() method is calling other service. If so you need to Mock that service as well.

Comment: Please see the full code in the recent edit and advice.
Thanks for your replies.

Comment: Can you past your exception logs and code of the method that your are covering.

Comment: @John i am not getting any logs for the same just the line number and the code is as follows -:
 public List<EligibilityCarrierGroupingDoc> getEcgs(DashboardRequest dashboardRequest) {
  
  List<EligibilityCarrierGroupingDoc> ecgData = mongoTemplate.findAll(EligibilityCarrierGroupingDoc.class);
  
  return ecgData;

Comment: You should try replacing .getEcgs(request) with .getEcgs(any())

Comment: @jeppz its not working with Mockito.any(Classname.class).

Comment: **@Mock** is used to define the mock object, while **@InjectMock** annotates the real object you want to test. I think you have just done the opposite...

Comment: @John this is correct .Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Why are you creating a new instance of `DashboardDaoImpl`? You have to mock it instead.

Comment: even though the question is closed , this might help you to find the answer. use @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)  in the class if you use Junit, if you use TestNG find the right runner.